# Resolution of abstract types in scala functions

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and trying to explore the syntax of the language, but I ran into an issue about abstract types.

```
def func5(x : Int, y : Int): Int = x * y
def func55(x : Double, y : Double): Double = x / y
def func6[A,B](f : (A,A) => A, g: (B,B) => B) :
  (Int,Int,Double,Double) => Double = (x,y,a,z) => {f(x,y)+g(a,z)}

func6(func5, func55)(3,4,7.0d,4.2d)
```

Here it gives me:

```
+g(a,z)} expected string but given B
```

Can someone enlight me about that ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your code assumes that the `+` function is defined for the types `A` and `B`, which might not be the case. Take a look at bounds.

Comment: Which tool gave you that error? Because when I compile your code I get other, more helpful, errors.

Comment: You're mixing generic and concrete types. You define `f()` to take `A` and `g()` to take `B`, but then you actually give them `Int` and `Double`, respectively. `A` and `B` are type parameters. They _might_ be number types, but they _might_ not, they're generic.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `func6` is trying to add a value of type `A` to a value of type `B`. Or more specifically, it is trying to call a method `+` on an object of type `A` with an argument of type `B`. Both `A` and `B` could be any type, and there isn't really a generic way to "add" two objects together.

So you might expect this to fail because there is no `+` operator on `A`. But Scala (for some reason) *does* have a generic definition of `+` for all objects. This generic `+` takes an argument of type `String` but `func6` is giving it type `B`, which is why you get the error

> found: B, required: String

Answer (score 0):

Functions f and g are generic functions, which do not take ints or doubles as arguments (only A and B).

```
        def func6[A,B](f : (A,A) => A, g: (B,B) => B) :
(A,A,B,B) => (A, B) = (x,y,a,z) => {
  (f(x,y),g(a,z))
}
```

Something like that will work. But you can not use '+' at the end of the function, because it is not defined for types A and B.

You could also define implicit plus operator for A and B.

```
  def func5(x : Int, y : Int): Int = x * y
  def func55(x : Double, y : Double): Double = x / y
  def func6[A,B](f : (A,A) => A, g: (B,B) => B)(implicit plusOperation: PlusOperation[A, B]) :
  (A,A,B,B) => B = (x,y,a,z) => {
    plusOperation.add(f(x,y),g(a,z))
  }

  trait PlusOperation[A, B] {
    def add(a: A, b: B): B
  }

  class IntToDoublePlus extends PlusOperation[Int, Double] {
    override def add(a: Int, b: Double): Double = a + b
  }


  implicit val plusOp: PlusOperation[Int, Double] = _ + _
  func6(func5, func55).apply(3,4,7.0d,4.2d)
```

Comment: Actually, `+` **is** defined for `A` via an implicit conversation, but it expects a value of type `String` not `B`, which is why you get that specific error.

Comment: @Tim But this + which is trying to be invoked by implicit conversion is String concatenation not the addition of two values.

Comment: Correct. That is why you get the error that the OP saw